# Programmatically animate a blender model — where to start?

Tags: python, 3d, blender

I have to create a simplistic 3D demo.

Having a model in Blender, I will write a python program that will:

- build a scene, set camera, draw an infinite plane, fill it with texture
- load a model (exported from Blender) and position the object
- handle key presses to produce the object moves

I need a link to descriptive tutorial(s) covering these 3 points:

- creating a 3d scene from Python program
- loading model from the file (of course I'm fine with any format, just letting you know that the source is created in Blender)
- catching key presses

No need in help on physics, or designing, only the principal programmatic part.

Thanks!

Comment: In what format have you exported the blender model? Wavefront obj?

Comment: as I wrote, I can export in any format you suggest assuming there's a reliable plugin

Comment: I believe blender supports exporting to Obj. I included a blog post link in my answer regarding how to load it from python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much to say: [OpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/) / [Glut](http://www.btinternet.com/~ahcox/PyGlut/)

Also, take a look at the [OpenGL red book](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/red_book/). You can read it online.
 [Samples](http://www.opengl.org/resources/code/samples/redbook/) are written in C, but can be easily ported to python, since function calls are the same.

[image]

As for loading the blender model, take a look at this:
[Loading wavefront obj files with python](http://www.nandnor.net/?p=86)

In a nutshell look for:

- [Push/Pop matrix](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/glPushMatrix.3G.html)
- [glTranslate](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/glTranslate.3G.html) / [glRotate](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/glRotate.3G.html) / [glScale](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/glScale.3G.html)
- [gluLookAt](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/gluLookAt.3G.html)
- define a function that and pass it to [glutKeyboardFunc](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/glutKeyboardFunc.3GLUT.html)

Comment: thanks, looks promising. currently looking into pyglet, though having issues installing it on OSX

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer as well-detailed, though still trying to cope with some higher-level frameworks like Panda3D

Answer (score 0):

To link components from another Blender file into your scene, you can use the Python API.
You can find all the documentation at: 
http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_59_0/contents.html

In particular, you probably will need:
bpy.data.libraries.load ( http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_59_0/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html#bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries ) to inspect the contents of a file, and bpy.ops.wm.link_append ( http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_59_0/bpy.ops.wm.html ) to import the objects you need from the specified file.

I only know how to catch keypresses while running the Game Engine. Is that what you are looking for?

Cheers